# Find max value for each partition in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a data as:

```
ID  Date1       VarA    
1   2005-01-02  x       
1   2021-01-02  20      
1   2021-01-01  y       
2   2020-12-20  No      
2   2020-12-19  10      
3   1998-05-01  0
```

Here is the R-code to reproduce the data

```
example = data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3),
                   Date1 = c('2005-01-02',
                             '2021-01-02',
                             '2021-01-01',
                             '2020-12-20',
                             '2020-12-19',
                             '1998-05-01'),
                   VarA = c('x','20','y','No', '10','0'))
```

I would prefer the solution to do following:

First, flag the maximum date in data.

```
ID  Date1       VarA    Last_visit
1   2005-01-02  x       0
1   2021-01-02  20      1
1   2021-01-01  y       0
2   2020-12-20  No      1
2   2020-12-19  10      0
3   1998-05-01  0       1
```

Finally, It should retain only where the Last_visit=1

```
ID  Date1       VarA    Last_visit
1   2021-01-02  20      1
2   2020-12-20  No      1
3   1998-05-01  0       1
```

I am requesting the intermediate steps as well to perform a sanity check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a new column after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
example %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Last_visit = +(row_number() %in% which.max(as.Date(Date1)))) %>%
  ungroup
```

and then `filter/slice` based on the column

```
example %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Last_visit = +(row_number() %in% which.max(as.Date(Date1)))) %>%
  slice_max(n = 1, order_by = Last_visit) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
     ID Date1      VarA  Last_visit
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <int>
1     1 2021-01-02 20             1
2     2 2020-12-20 No             1
3     3 1998-05-01 0              1
```

---

Another option is to convert the 'Date1' to `Date` class first, then do an `arrange` and use `distinct`

```
example %>% 
  mutate(Date1 = as.Date(Date1)) %>%
  arrange(ID, desc(Date1)) %>%
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Last_visit = 1)
  ID      Date1 VarA Last_visit
1  1 2021-01-02   20          1
2  2 2020-12-20   No          1
3  3 1998-05-01    0          1
```

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun! This does exactly what I had asked for. :)